# Default path/IP for python repository using pip

Tags: networking, python

I am using Python 3.6.5 version (from Anaconda distribution) on Windows 10 platform. Whenever I try to install any packages in office, I get the following error:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))'
```

However, pip install seems to work fine over my home network. I guess the firewall in the office is blocking the connection. I need to give URL / IP of the repo path in order to get it white-listed.

I had shared the following links earlier with my IT team:
https://pypi.org/*
https://files.pythonhosted.org/*

But still the issue is not resolved. Could someone help me in getting the right repo path for pip install command? Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks.